# Why would Google Tag Manager not fire a tag set to fire on "All pages"?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having a real tricky problem with Google Tag Manager on my site.

On certain paths under my domain, GTM will load (Tag Assistant shows the right container loading, and the GTM console pops up when Debug mode is enabled) but not fire any tags, *even tags set to fire on all pages*. This is using the default regex for the All Pages rule, ".*" I know this since the Debug console shows all the tags in the container as "Not fired".

On the root of my domain, GTM works just fine and the container loads while tags fire as they should.

I even opened the Chrome console and got the current location with "window.location.href" - it returned the path, minus the hostname, of the page I was on as expected.

What possible situation would cause GTM to load properly on a page, but not fire All Pages tags?

Comment: window.location.href should return the full url including the hostname. Are you tampering with location values somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If the GTM container is loading properly but the tags aren't firing, that's because the tags that you want to fire have prerequisites that need to be completed before firing. By prerequisites, I mean that some action has to happen before a user reaches the page you want the tag to fire on for it to fire.

For example, If you are trying to fire a Google Adwords conversion code on a thank-you page. That conversion code won't fire unless someone actually came to your site after clicking on an Adwords ad. If a person came organically, then that tag shouldn't fire, otherwise all your conversion reporting would be over counted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure the rules for each tag/URL are set correctly. Then use the preview & debug option to check for firing. This is most probably caused by incorrect rule parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem which i found an answer to. After creating your tags and linking the 
macros properly, preview in debug mode, it should FIRE. But take note that it wont count on Adword Conversion account.

I think you add a rule dat says  **gtm.formSubmit**  it worked for me. 
Try it out.